# FlashDevelop Haxe (Flash) debugger

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, haxe

Is there any debugger for Haxe in FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlashDevelop now ships with a Haxe debugger which works well (Flash target only).